# Selenium C# Script to test the standard login password requirements

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Is there any Selenium C# Script available to test the standard login password requirements e,g

> To Register you must use a password with at least eight characters
>   and contain at least three of the following: • Uppercase alphabetic
>   character; • Lowercase alphabetic character; • Numeric character;
>   and/or • Special character

Any script that can generate random passwords, following the above criteria to register a new user successfully or not (positive and negative)

Comment: Why can't you write your own?

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work for you. You can add characters accordingly and define the length as well.

```
public static string GetRandomString(int length)
{
  var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  var random = new Random();
  var result = new string(
    Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
      .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
      .ToArray());
  return result;
}
```

Comment: What about lowercase and special character? Your answer does not cover that.

Answer (score 0):

The question is more related to QA theory than to Selenium. You should no test random cases. You should test all possible verification zones.
You should prepare test data first and then verify that after the execution of that cases - the expected result is correct.
And you probably should use [Test Design Techniques](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/black-box-test-design-techniques/) for more option test data creation.

In your situation you should verify the following cases:

1. Aaaaa1! (7 symbols) - fail
2. Aaaaaa1! (8 symbols) - pass
3. Aaaaaaa1! (9 symbols) - pass
4. (very long password) - ???
5. Aaaaaa11 (no symbols) - pass
6. Aaaaaaa! (no numbers) - pass
7. aaaaaa1! (no upper case) - fail
8. AAAAAA1! (no lower case) - fail
9. 1111111! (no alphabetic) - fail
10. 11111111 (only numbers) - fail
11. !@#$%^&* (only symbols) - fail
12. (empty) - fail